# openssh client - inside of ~/.ssh/config determine IdentityFile at run time

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am trying to determine if it is possible to dynamically (at run time) specify the `IdentityFile` within a `Host` directive inside of the standard ssh config file at `~/.ssh/config`.

If this is the current directive.

```
Host server
  HostName server.example.com
  User foo
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo.pem
```

Ideally I would want to run a generic executable that returns the path to the private key.

```
Host server
  HostName server.example.com
  User foo
  IdentityFile generic-executable %h %r
```

or

```
Host server
  HostName server.example.com
  User foo
  IdentityFile $(generic-executable %h %r)
```

This executable would take the hostname and remote user as input and spit out the path to a pem file.

Certainly open to other ways to accomplish the same end goal (without using `-i` on the command line).

The use case here is that I have `ProxyCommand` generating an ephemeral SSH key and pushing it via AWS EC2 Instance Connect to and EC2 instance and then printing the necessary AWS CLI command to establish a session manager tunnel over which SSH will be proxied.

```
ProxyCommand eval $(ssm-proxy -h %h -u %r -p %p -P)
```

The AWS pieces of this I believe to be immaterial to the ultimate question which is why I have not tagged this question with an AWS tag.

Comment: I don't entirely follow the use case, but I suspect the solution would be to use an `ssh-agent` to which the ephemeral key is pushed?

Comment: @chepner thanks for the suggestion. will certainly read up on `ssh-agent`.

Comment: so it seems with ssh-agent we will have to provide something in the IndentityFile - it is just the path to the public key. which puts me right back in the same spot on how to dynamically change that at run time. could of course be missing something here.

Comment: The idea is that the SSH client doesn't specify *anything* statically to connect; it simply looks to see what is in the SSH client. Whatever generates the key is supposed to put it in the agent for the client. As far as I know, the only way to make SSH execute an external command is using a `Match` directive, which is just used to select whether a block of configuration options is applicable to a given invocation.

Comment: Maybe `Match exec ...` in order to execute a pre-populated file via `Include` that contains the necessary key?

Comment: oh wow, with the `ssh-agent` option i just removed the `IdentityFile` from the ssh config and it worked. nice! in my reading it seemed like the public key had to be referenced. this may very well work. i am also going to explore `Include` as it could be a good alternative for users who don't want to use `ssh-agent` for some reason.